# Non-CALayer animation framework for arbitrary objects and properties

Tags: objective-c, ios, animation, frameworks

I've searched and searched and can't seem to find either a way to use CoreAnimation to animate properties on objects of custom classes or a 3rd party framework to accomplish the task.  Can anyone shed some light on the subject?

My particular use case is that I wish to animate a property which gets passed as an OpenGL uniform on each draw.

Comment: custom subclasses of what?  which properties exactly do you want to animate?  what does "OpenGL uniform" mean? why not CALayer? that _is_ how to animate properties of UIView/CALayer.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  To answer your questions:  a subclass of NSObject; an arbitrary property that I've created;  OpenGLES 2 GLSL shader uniform variable which you set prior to drawing with glUniform1f().  Can one animate custom properties on a CALayer subclass?  Regardless, I'm controlling a generic GLKView via a delegate so I don't actually have the means to create a new property on the layer unless I do some tedious refactoring.  I'm envisioning an API along the lines of [ANAnimationClass animiationWithObject:someObject forKeyPath:"someproperty" startValue/timingFunction, etc]

Comment: "Can one animate custom properties on a CALayer subclass"? Certainly. That is one of the main virtues of the way CALayer is constructed. (See my explanation here: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch17.html#_making_a_property_animatable) That doesn't mean, however, that it can be done for _this_ property, the nature of which I do not at all understand.

Answer (score 0):

Two fine options I've discovered:

**PRTween:** https://github.com/domhofmann/PRTween

and

**POP (by Facebook):** https://github.com/facebook/pop

PRTween wins on simplicity...

`[PRTween tween:someObject property:@"myProp" from:1 to:0 duration:3];`

POP has some interesting animation curves developed for the FB Paper app. It's a bit more convoluted for custom props but gives you more flexibility w/o further digging:

```
POPSpringAnimation *anim = [POPSpringAnimation animation];    
prop = [POPAnimatableProperty propertyWithName:@"com.foo.radio.volume" initializer:^(POPMutableAnimatableProperty *prop) {
  // read value
  prop.readBlock = ^(id obj, CGFloat values[]) {
    values[0] = [obj volume];
  };
  // write value
  prop.writeBlock = ^(id obj, const CGFloat values[]) {
    [obj setVolume:values[0]];
  };
  // dynamics threshold
  prop.threshold = 0.01;
}];

anim.property = prop;
```